# Android data display in wrong format from JSONObject to ListView

Tags: android, listview

I try to display 2 column data with `HashMap` and `Listview`, it works fine. The error comes when I try to display more than 2 columns.

**2_columns.java**

```
public class Main4Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

String url = "http://192.168.1.103/web_service/omg.php/";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "ID";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "Name";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main4);

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        try {
            Iterator<String> iterator = response.keys();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String key = iterator.next();
                String value = response.getString(key);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put(COLUMN_ID, key);
                map.put(COLUMN_NAME, value);

                aList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(aList.size() > 0) {
            String[] from = {COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_NAME};
            int[] to = {R.id.text_id, R.id.text_name};
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Main4Activity.this, aList, R.layout.list_item, from, to);
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
            }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("error", "error ");
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
}
```

**localhost/web_service/omg.php**

```
{
"32":"Western Food",
"33":"Chinese Food",
"34":"Mix Food",
"35":"Japanese Food",
"36":"Korean Food",
"37":"Italian Food",
"38":"German Food"
}
```

[image]

The above coding is working fine. But the errors come when I try to display data in multiple columns,

**multiple_columns.java**

```
String url = "http://192.168.1.103/web_service/ohno.php/";

private static final String product_sku = "SKU";
private static final String product_name = "Name";
private static final String product_price = "Price";
private static final String product_quantity = "Quantity";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            try {
                Iterator<String> iterator = response.keys();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    String key = iterator.next();
                    String value_sku = response.getString(key);
                    String value_name= response.getString(key);
                    String value_price= response.getString(key);
                    String value_quantity= response.getString(key);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put(product_sku, value_sku);
                    map.put(product_name, value_name);
                    map.put(product_price, value_price);
                    map.put(product_quantity, value_quantity);

                    aList.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(aList.size() > 0) {
                String[] from = {product_sku,product_name, product_price,product_quantity};
                int[] to = {R.id.sku,R.id.name, R.id.price,R.id.quantity};
                SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Main5Activity.this, aList, R.layout.list_item2, from, to);
                ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("error", "error ");
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
```

**localhost/web_service/ohno.php**

```
{
"482":["1","Chicken Rice","1","1"],
"483":["1","French Fries","1","1"],
"484":["1","apple","1","1"],
"492":["1","western+italian","1","1"],
"493":["1","no_cat","1","1"]
}
```

[image]

As you can see from the above screenshot, I want the Key to be 482,483,484... and the value its on the right side. What's wrong with the coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the values in your JSON are `JSONArray`s, so `response.getString(key)` will return the whole array as a `String`.

Call `getJSONArray()` to get the values as a `JSONArray`, so you can process the items individually.

Something like this should work:

```
try {
    Iterator<String> iterator = response.keys();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = iterator.next();
        JSONArray array = response.getJSONArray(key);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put(product_sku, array.getString(0));
        map.put(product_name, array.getString(1));
        map.put(product_price, array.getString(2));
        map.put(product_quantity, array.getString(3));

        aList.add(map);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing `JSONArray` as using `JSONObject` which is wrong. So Try as follows

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

try {
    Iterator<String> iterator = response.keys();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = iterator.next();
        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray(key);
        String value_sku = jsonArray.get(0).toString();
        String value_name = jsonArray.get(1).toString();
        String value_price = jsonArray.get(2).toString();
        String value_quantity = jsonArray.get(3).toString();

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(product_sku, value_sku);
        map.put(product_name, value_name);
        map.put(product_price, value_price);
        map.put(product_quantity, value_quantity);

        aList.add(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: btw, for your coding, possible to extend to onclick listener?