# Android convert JsonArray to Array in Listview with BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview

I have setup a **Listview with BaseAdapter** and so far its working fine with **setOnItemClickListener**. But it's hard coding.

[image]

**Main2Activity.java**

```
String sku[]={"1","2","3","4"};
String name[]={"Bad Food","Very Bad Food","Extremly Bad Food","Super Bad Food"};
String price[]={"99","999","9999","99999"};
String quantity[]={"123","456","789","101112"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(new my_adapter(Main2Activity.this,sku,name,price,quantity));

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Sku->"+sku[i]
                    +" Name->"+name[i]
                    +" Price->"+price[i]
                    +" Quantity->"+quantity[i]
                    ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

**my_adapter.java**

```
public class my_adapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context ctx;
LayoutInflater inflater=null;

String sku[];
String name[];
String price[];
String quantity[];

public my_adapter(Context ctx, String sku[], String name[], String price[],String quantity[]){
    this.ctx=ctx;
    this.sku=sku;
    this.name=name;
    this.price=price;
    this.quantity=quantity;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return sku.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View row=view;

    if(row==null){
        inflater=(LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.rows,null);
    }

    TextView product_sku=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.sku);
    TextView product_name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView product_price=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.price);
    TextView product_quantity=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.quantity);

    product_sku.setText(sku[i]);
    product_name.setText(name[i]);
    product_price.setText(price[i]);
    product_quantity.setText(quantity[i]);

    return row;
}
}
```

Next, I need to do something similar which is to **convert JsonArray to Array and then use it in setOnItemClickListener.** That means, I need to store all the data from json into 4 arrays and then use any of the elements later on when they click on the item. Just like my hard coding example.

I have seen some examples with HashMap as well as some JsonArray to array templates coding but not sure how to combine them with my ListView and baseAdapter.

**getting json data**

```
JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        // working with HashMap or Arraylist?????
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
requestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

**localhost/web_service/ohno.php**

```
{
"482":["1","Chicken Rice","1","1"],  //Unique ID, sku,name,price,quantity
"483":["1","French Fries","1","1"],
"484":["1","apple","1","1"],
"492":["1","western+italian","1","1"],
"493":["1","no_cat","1","1"]
}
```

The format that I have setup in Listview is exactly same as The above Json format(4 columns) except Json format has an extra element that is Unique product ID.

Comment: so whats unclear in `org.json.JSONObject` API?

Comment: @pskink http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39425837/android-data-display-in-wrong-format-from-jsonobject-to-listview/39425991?noredirect=1#comment66176097_39425991  ysd I have asked some related questions(simple adapter) BUT that one are mainly Strings. But my above example is Array, any example that works something similar?

Comment: ok, so whats unclear in `org.json.JSONArray` API?

Comment: the following link will help you  [link] (https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http)

Comment: @pskink I think I should put it in a simple and clearer way. please have a look at this screenshot -> http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=758485c    .The json data I posted in question is exactly the same as the URL screenshot(mobile version)  . What i am trying to do is that get the Json data from mysqli and then display it in Listview , when clicking on the item, it wil open in Dialog. With the unique ID, I can update and delete accordingly. By explaining this, do you have a clearer picture?

Comment: so did you even try to play with `org.json.JSONObject` API? if so, where is your code?

Comment: @pskink hmm, I think yes? I did try ysd . Here is another question i asked ysd -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39424112/android-convert-jsonobject-to-hashmap-and-display-in-listview-with-simpleadapter

Comment: you have the accepted answer there, so whats the problem?

Comment: pskink understands you perfectly fine, but it seems, that you haven't even tried to accomplish the task yourself. SO questions should contain a specific problem with a description of what you have tried so far and what difficulties you encountered, it is not a place to outsource your work ("Questions asking us to recommend or find a [...] tutorial [...] are off-topic" http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Guys, I think what's wrong with the coding after pskink has hinted me. I think its the constructor in baseadapater that doesn't suit my siutation. Please wait for a while, I am modifying it now and come back later if the issus still there

Comment: you have working solution with `SimpleAdapter` so just use that adapter in `setOnItemClickListener` method

Comment: @pskink: I said you (hence no @ before your name) understood gosulove and tried to point out, that he should have a look at the API, I wasn't speaking to you.

Comment: @pskink but that solution, I couldn't get other data except the position. I need every element in the Array

Comment: @F.Klein ah ok sorry for misunderstanding...

Comment: @F.Klein I think you have misunderstood me.

Comment: so read `Adapter` API, hint: `adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(positionInAdapter)`

Comment: @pskink still working. in fact, its abit confusing for me now as information overload.

Comment: what do you mean? did you call `getItem` or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123090/discussion-between-gosulove-and-pskink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be ideal to actually create a Model class or say POJO class with member variables like sku, name, price, quantity, id. The code may look like

```
public class Item {
    private int id;
    private String sku;
    private String name;
    private String price;
    private String quantity;
}
```

After getting the json parse it and create a list of Item something like

```
public void parseJson(String data) {
    ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

    //Parsing logic goes here
}
```

Once you are done with creating list of items you can have an ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter accept that and then just iterate over the list and set appropriate values. This, to me, seems to be correct approach rather than creating separate arrays and then passing it to BaseAdapter.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: sounds ok, trying it now. Just to confirm that public class Item  is in my_adapter.java and public void parseJson(String data) in Main2Activity.java?

Comment: It's upto you how you design it. Item can be an altogether an independent class. You can also have a look at JSON marshalling using JacksonJson or GSON. I think you are using Volley for making Http calls and there is a way of using JacksonJson with Volley.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
  public void getJson() { 
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(localhost/web_service/ohno.php, new JsonHttpResponseHandler()   {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
            ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
            JSONArray jsonArray482=response.optJSONArray("482");
            if (jsonArray482 != null) {
                for (int i=0;i<jsonArray482.length();i++){
                    try {
                        listData.add(jsonArray482.get(i).toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    });
}
```